# Issue starting up docker-compose.yml file: [sh: 1: webpack-dev-server: not found, sh: 1: nodemon: not found]

Tags: docker, npm, docker-compose, dockerfile

So currently, I am trying to run my docker-compose-dev-hot.yml file, but when I run
'docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev-hot.yml up', I keep getting the error below:

I'm quite sure everything is set up correctly (I was told not to change anything in my webpack either). I'm not sure as to why it says nodemon and webpack aren't found because in the dockerfile-dev file I'm clearly doing npm install to install the necessary dependecies.

**Error:**
[image]

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:10.1
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN npm i
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 3000
ENTRYPOINT node ./server/server.js
```

**Dockerfile-dev**

```
FROM node:10.15
RUN npm i -g webpack  
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm i
EXPOSE 3000
```

**docker-compose-dev-hot.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  dev:
    image: orgname/mm-dev
    container_name: mm-dev-hot
    ports: 
    - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
    - .:/usr/src/app
    - node_modules:/usr/src/app/node_modules
    command: npm run dev:hot
volumes: 
  node_modules:
```

**Package.JSON**

```
{
    "name": " - ",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": " - ",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "webpack --config ./webpack.config.js",
        "start": "node ./server/server.js",
        "dev:hot": "NODE_ENV=development nodemon ./server/server.js & webpack-dev-server --open --hot --inline --progress --colors --watch --content-base ./",
        "docker-dev:hot": "docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev-hot.yml up",
        "test": "NODE_ENV=test jest --coverage"
    },
    "author": "Schno Mozingo",
    "license": "MIT",
    "dependencies": {
        "buffer-shims": "^1.0.0",
        "pg": "^7.7.1",
        "react": "^16.5.2",
        "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
        "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
        "redux": "^3.7.2",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
        "css-loader": "^1.0.1",
        "cssloader": "^1.1.1",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
        "jest": "^24.1.0",
        "morgan": "^1.9.1",
        "nodemon": "^1.18.9",
        "react-hot-loader": "^4.6.3",
        "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.5",
        "ret": "^0.2.2",
        "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
        "webpack": "^4.44.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
        "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.24.3"
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the value of `NODE_ENV`? and try to remove `node_modules:/usr/src/app/node_modules` this mapping and then try again

Comment: Can you skip all of the Docker setup, and just `npm run dev:host` using the host's Node installation instead?  (Why is Docker involved here at all?)